# If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^p$, then every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S \implies S$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^p$, then every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S \implies  S$ is closed.

> My query is :  Isn't the above statement self proving? Every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$ means that every limit point belongs to $S$. Hence, $S$ must be closed.

However, the proof in my book goes like this :

$1.$ Let $x$ be an accumulation point of $S$.

$2.$ Define a countable number of neighbourhoods $B(x,\dfrac {1} {k}) ; k=1,2,\cdots$

$3.$ Obtain a countable number of distinct points $x_k$ such that $x_k \in B(x,\dfrac {1} {k})$

$4.$ Proving that $\lim~ x_k=x$

Why is step $4$ necessary? Isn't just the condition that every limit point of $S$ belongs to S sufficient to prove that $S$ is closed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ the right statement is: Every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$ $\iff$ $S$ is compact ( closed and bounded).

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the proof of the part in which it's shown to be closed

Comment: The tag ([tag:general-topology]) seems to be used for topics from [point-set topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_topology), so I have [edited the tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/951232/revisions). BTW I am not sure why you chose ([tag:elementary-number-theory]) for your question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak My bad. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that every infinite subset has **an** accumulation point in $S$.

This does not (directly) say that **every** accumulation point of every infinite set is also in $S$.

Hence, in step (4) you show that $x$ is the **only** accumulation point of the set $\{x_k \mid k\}$.

Then, there must be **some** accumulation point $y$ of $\{x_k \mid k\}$ such that $y \in S$. But by uniqueness, $x = y \in S$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :-)